# API KEY Google MAPS para meus clientes com aplicativo feito em Delphi

Tags: delphi, api-key

Criei um aplicativo para computador onde o usuário pode rastrear seus entregadores usando a API do Google Maps. O navegador é o componente **TChromium** - para Delphi que substitui o **TWebBrowser**.

Até aí tudo bem, gerei minha chave API_KEY e funciona tudo certo.
Mas minha dúvida é: E quando eu vender o meu aplicativo? O meu cliente irá usar esta mesma chave ? Ou deverá criar uma chave para ele ?

Digo isto porque não sei como irei controlar minha quota de acesso á API. Já que, pelo que entendí, é limitado a uma certa quantidade de acesso por dia, depois disto, terá que ser pago um valor ao Google.

Exemplo: Se eu vender 100 cópias de meu aplicativo, não tenho como saber quantos acessos serão feito no período de 24 horas...

Teria eu entendido errado? Alguém está passando por isto?

Comment: A Google disponibilizou 2500 acessos por dia como cortesia, passou desse limite por dia será cobrado em torno de R$1,50 dependendo o dolar com isso eles adicionam mais 1000 acessos a sua cota ou pagar uma quantia para ter 100 mil acessos por dia. Tens como verificar nesse link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Comment: Sim, mas devo vender meu aplicativo com minha chave (api_key) ? Ou cada cliente meu deverá gerar sua própria chave? tem esta informação ?

Comment: Quando você gera API Key, provavelmente tens que colocar no mapa para poder funcionar, você gera o executável e essa api key vai junto para os seus clientes poderem acessar o mapa, você deve imaginar quantos acessos vão ter, pela quantidade de clientes e como a sua aplicação vai ser usada por eles.

Comment: Aí que está o problema, a api_key vai no arquivo html/JavaScrit. Qualquer um pode vê-la. Não é compilada.

Comment: Aí que está o problema, a api_key vai no arquivo html/JavaScrit. Não é compilada. Então, eu penso que poderia criar uma chave para cada cliente, mas não sei como o google controla isto... Tentei falar com eles, sem sucesso. No site developers.google, não está claro isto (ou não consegui entender direito). Me parece que, para uso comercial ou para grandes quantidades de acesso á api, teria que adquirir a LICENÇA PREMIUM, entretanto, não consegui entender como isto funciona, se sou eu que devo fazer a licença e enviar para o cliente ou ele mesmo faria e eu deixaria um campo no app para inseri-la